# Allow IP through htaccess using Cloudflare Proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, ip, apache2, cloudflare

I'm using

```
Allow from 123.234.12.23
```

to whitelist IP addresses without needing to enter in the htpasswd credentials.

I've just switched to use Cloudflare proxy (to protect bypassing CF firewall) but now all requests to my server (from Apache logs) are coming in as Cloudflare IP's.

---

How can I access the requester's actual IP so that I don't have to keep entering in the credentials if I'm on a whitelisted IP?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to install `mod_cloudflare` for Apache.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170916-Restoring-original-visitor-IPs-Option-1-Installing-mod-cloudflare

---

Since my machine was running on Ubuntu, I ended up following the guide from [this site](https://emtunc.org/blog/01/2016/installing-mod_cloudflare-ubuntu-14-04-apache-server/) which worked for me to install it on Ubuntu.

Comment: `mod_cloudflare` has not been supported since Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (2016). You should use `mod_remoteip` instead.

Comment: @BadHorsie I do use it, I never had a chance to update my answer...